# Python ignoring leading whitespace when doing .replace on dataframe column with strings

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, whitespace

I have a dataframe column which generally contains numeric but some entries are written as `'No Data'`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,2,3,' No Data',4,5,6]})
```

However, some entries, like in the above example,  may start with a whitespace as `' No Data'`. I am trying to find an efficient way to replace all `No Data` entries with `NaN` without worrying about that extra space. For now, what I have is

```
df['group'].replace('No Data', np.nan)
print df
```

Which does not work unless I put a space in search term like

```
df['group'].replace(' No Data', np.nan)
```

While this works, I was hoping there is a better way I can do it without checking for extra space.

**Note** : I can also achieve this by `list comprehension` and using `in`

```
[np.nan if 'No Data' in str(x) else x for x in df['group']]
```

which will work just fine but I think `replace` is more readable.

Comment: @idjaw. Thanks. There the columns is all strings and some tricks like map(str.strip) works well. Here because of numeric entries, that does not work.  The accepted answer there involves writing a function which I do not want to, since the two alternatives I posted works well. I am just trying to see if there is even better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by integrating a regex into the `replace` function that you suggest:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,2,3,' No Data',4,5,6]})

df = df.replace(r'No Data', np.nan, regex=True)
print df
```

**Output**

```
   group
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
4      4
5      5
6      6
```

Using the regex `r'No data'` will look for the string `'No data'` anywhere in your cell. If it finds a match, the cell will be replaced with `np.nan`.

An alternative would be to use `applymap` to apply a simple lambda function to each cell in the dataframe. I think this is a pretty readable solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,2,3,' No Data',4,5,6]})

df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if type(x) == str and 'No Data' in x else x)
print df
```

**Output**

```
   group
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
4      4
5      5
6      6
```

Comment: Thanks @gtlambert. Both the alternatives are great and love the `regex` method.

Comment: looks like I do not even need to add `r` Just using `'No Data'` with `regex=True` seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Pandas allows you to use regular expressions with the replace function so you can do:

```
df['group'].replace("\s*No Data", np.nan, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @bunji. I tried exactly that but did not put regex=True !